# Oceanographic depth map - get depth of given coordinate in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, image-processing, coordinates

I’m working on a quite simple web implementation for route planning, or actually more an implementation that illustrates the value of it. What i want to do is to be to plot the water depth along my path. I’m using JavaScript and some php in the background. My map is a google map.

To find the data is simple (http://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gridded_bathymetry_data/) but I need some help to implement in on a website. I have tried to export some data to an asci-file, read it with PHP and extract a coordinate close to my position. This works for small areas but the amount of data is big, for a small area between Denmark-Sweden-Norway I have 100 000 coordinates. I want a better part of the globe. 
The up side is that I don’t care too much about the actual depth, only some intervals. 0-5, 5-10, 10-20, and >20 meter. It is also not really important to know if I hit land, it would be neat but if i get the first part working it should be easy.

The data I got have a resolution of 1 meter, it is reasonable easy to draw a map with whatever interval I want but my question is if you have any Idea of how I can check the depth of a coordinate without storing so much data.

One alternative is to generate images and check the colour of a certain pixel, that I calculate from a lat-long coordinate that I get from the map. Is there a neater way to store the data without having to store every coordinate individually?

I have linked to an image that I hope illustrate what I want to do. Plot a route and get the general depth for every waypoint.
http://s15.postimg.org/gmf8wxu1n/depthmap.gif

Comment: have you considered to store the map inside MySQL in vector form that should handle the storage load instead of PHP, to speed up the queries you can sort the data spatially (into regions) so you can compute your queries faster ...

Comment: No. I had an idea to store the coordinates in a database before I realised how big earth is. This sounds like a good idea though, I will look into it.